# Simple cross platform style guide for mobile apps or a recommended approach?

Tags: mobile-application, style-guide

Having joined a new project recently I've found a lot of padding / margin sizes etc set in the App which had variuous names and isn't consistent.

I've also been briefly looking at style guides blog posts.

I'm trying to come up with a simple style guide, which will cater font sizes, margins and padding.

However, I'm trying to arrive at something simply which will cater for most scenarios.

I've previously encountered policies based on a number aka 4 or 5 and margins had to be multiples of that. I think that was along the lines of bootstrap.

Can anyone point me at something similar which would work for Android and iOS...

Answer (score 1):

Most designers that I have worked with in the past are really committed to [Material Design](https://material.io/design). The really great thing about Material Design is that it is based in good design principles instead of design dogma. As a matter of fact, they actually have guidelines for [iOS apps](https://material.io/develop/ios) which some Apple enthusiast may find blasphemous :).

In addition to that, always keep in mind the visual identity of your app. If some elements in your design system break general design guidelines, it is not the end of the world. A combination of something like Material Design principles and the branding of the application is a starting point for me when I take on new projects.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what happens with sizes for margins and padding etc. Couldn’t see that on the md site.

Comment: Please refer to to this: https://material.io/design/layout/responsive-layout-grid.html#columns-gutters-and-margins and if you have any other questions after reading leave them here :)

Comment: Thanks again, I guess I was hoping to see something resembling a style sheet. Something which shows types of naming fir different scenarios.

Comment: Are you referring to something like a Design System? Such as how to properly present elements like typography, colors, buttons in different states?

Comment: I guess so. Something to simply express different sizes, margins / padding etc. I’be used bootstrap for web in the past. And previously used units of 4 or 5 etc. But need something simple.

Comment: The need to assign values to names.

Comment: I would still recommend you read the entire design guidelines of material design and you will surely find all the answers there. Especially this part https://material.io/design/layout/responsive-layout-grid.html#breakpoints . I haven't used bootstrap in ages. I hope somebody else here might be more helpful